# Bootstrap: Horizontally align buttons - getting overlapped

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add 2 buttons to an aspx page and have used bootstrap. The 2 buttons are getting mingled/overlapped on top of each other. How to have buttons aligned horizontally and have a logical space in between the buttons. I have tried the below code:

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="btn-group buttons" style="margin-left:80px !important;" id="divDefBtn" runat="server" visible="false">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
      <asp:Button ID="btnRun" runat="server" Text="Run " CssClass="btn btn-primary"
             OnClick="btnRun_Click" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group buttons" id="divExport" runat="server" visible="false">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
      <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
             OnClick="btnExport_Click"  />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have 20 columns in your grid row, but bootstrap expects (up to) 12.  Swap your col-sm-* divs with your btn-group divs, and adjust so that your column total = 12.

Comment: Resolved this by using - display:inline-block; vertical-align:top and the top div class as - btn-group